# nginx.conf with RTMP module: Add watermark on MULTIPLE video streams withh ffmpeg

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I need to add a watermark in nginx.conf on all my output streams. This is what I found from the documentation from ffmpeg but it is not working.

```
exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/$app/$name -i /mnt/pictures/flowtech.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10,split=5[out1][out2][out3][out4][out5]"
-map '[out1]' -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:v 256k -b:a 32k -vf "scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hlsall/$name_low
-map '[out2]' -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:v 768k -b:a 96k -vf "scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hlsall/$name_mid
-map '[out3]' -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:v 1024k -b:a 128k -vf "scale=960:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hlsall/$name_high
-map '[out4]' -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:v 1920k -b:a 128k -vf "scale=1280:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hlsall/$name_hd720
-map '[out5]' -map 0:a -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/hlsall/$name_src 1>>/tmp/rtmp_log;
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: @Gyan From commandline: Filtergraph 'scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.

Comment: Ok, I understand. -ad and complex filetr cannot be used in the same stream. I remove af and it is working. No I need to find out how to change quality in complex filter.

Comment: -vf "scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" in filter_complex but is different per stream output

Answer (score 0):

This is working:
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/app/tria_cam2 -i /mnt/pictures/flowtech.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10,split=2[out1][out2]" -map '[out1]' -map 0:a -s 640x480 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:v 256k -b:a 32k  -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hlsall/tria_cam6 -map '[out2]' -map 0:a -s 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:v 768k -b:a 96k  -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hlsall/tria_cam5